# functional subrings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

I should recall the notion of maximal subring of a commutative unitary ring $R$.

> **Def:** A commutative ring $S$ is called a maximal subring of $R$ if $S \subset R$ and if $T \subset R$ constitute a commutative ring with the restricted addition and multiplication of $R$ and also $S\subsetneq T$ then we could deduce that $T=R$.

I am interested in studing this notion in **Rings of continuous functions**.

We could easily deduce that for $x \neq y \in X$ The set of the form $$M_{x,y}=\Big(f\in C(X): f(x)=f(y) \Big)$$ forms a maximal subring of $C(X)$

From the above summary and notations I could pose my Questions.

> **Question1:** Is there a maximal subring in $C(X)$ other than  all $M_{x,y}$'s?
>
> **Question2:** Is $X$ compact if all maximal subrings of $C(X)$ is of the form $M_{x,y}$?

---

PS:I suppose that all subrings of a commutative ring $R$ contains the unitary element of $R$.

Comment: Fix $x\in X$. What about the set $M_x$ of elements $f\ in C(X)$ such that $f(x)=0$? 

Comment: Hello Dear Alireza. If you notice to my postscript which was added at the end of my problems you could find that $M_x$ is not a subring of $C(X)$, because $1\notin M_x$.

Comment: I assume you mean --closed subrings--. By Zorn's lemma argument there are lots of maximal subrings of $\mathbb{C}=C(\{\emptyset\})$.

Comment: Dear Ollie, My notation of $C(X)$ consider all continuous real valued functions. On the other hand I do not understand How you could apply Zorn's lemma for this situation. Please describe in more details. Thanks a lot.Also How could you deduce that $\mathbb {C}= C(\{\emptyset \})$ contains a proper maximal subring.

Comment: Partially order the proper subrings of $\mathbb{R}$ by inclusion. Then for any chain $(R_i)\_{i\in I}$ the proper subring $R=\cup_{i\in I}R_i$ is an upper bound. Thus by Zorn's lemma there exists a maximal proper subring.  

Comment: @Ollie, You have said that for the chain $(R_i)_{i\in I}$, $R=\cup_{i\in I} R_i$ is also proper. Why do you sure that this subring is proper? I think one of the conditions for applying the Zorn argument fails and that is being proper of the mentioned subring.  

Comment: @AliReza Start with the ring of integers. Well order the reals. 
At each stage, add the next real to your growing subring 
iff the resulting subring does not have 1/2 as an element.

Comment: @Alireza hum, you are right, frustrating!
@David this was my first approach, but I cannot make it work. You end up with a maximal subring not containing 1/2. However this just says that any $R$ with $M\subset R\subset C(X)$ contains 1/2, not that R=C(X).
Still, even if I can't non-constructively construct them there are maximal subrings:
http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219498810004208?journalCode=jaa


Comment: Note you might as well take X compact, since $C(X)=C(\beta X)$ (in the nonunital case it's different). For $X$ not compact you get extra maximal subrings $M\_{x,y}$ corresponding to "points at infinity".

Comment: @Ollie, $C(X)=C(\beta X)$ only holds if all continuous functions on $X$ are bounded. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,
Yes, C(X) has very different maximal subrings. First note that the real line, say R, has uncountable many maximal subrings, see  for example A. Azarang and O.A.S. Karamzadeh works about the existence of maximal subrings in Fields and Commutative Rings, Hence for any fixed maximal ideal M_x of C(X), C(X) contains many maximal subrings different from the above. Also note that for any free maximal ideal M, C(X) contains a maximal subring which contains R.

Comment: Thanks dear Alborz. I think you are skilled in the existence of maximal subrings. could you think about the second Question.If you are familiar with the kolmogoroff theorem in characterization of maximal ideals of C(X), when X is compact, You could find that it's a bit similar to it. cheers

Answer (score 3):

Question 1 has a positive answer for general $X$. The reason for this is that $C(X)$ cannot distinguish between $X$ and its realcompactification.  Hence if $X$ is not realcompact we construct $M_{x,y}$ as above with $x$ in $X$ and with $y$ in the realcompactification, but not in $X$.  This is a maximal subring which does not have the required form.

A good reference for this material is Weir's book "Hewitt-Nachbin spaces" (and, of course, Gilman and Jerison).

Comment: Dear jbc. Thank you so much for your nice and simple construction, from your answer for part 1 of my Question, we could deduce that if the condition of part 2 occurs, then $X$ should be real compact. but it also remains to approach to the compactness of it. Best wishes 

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that $C(X)$ actually separates the points of $X$. Otherwise one could have $M_{x,y}=C(X)$.

Comment: Dear Josh. Thank you very much for your notation. but it's better to see that in the study of rings of continuous functions, we could suppose that the topological space that all continuous functions defined on it, is completely regular Hausdorff space. then the case which you mentioned as an answer could not occur. As you Know for every topological space $X$ there exists a completely regular Hausdorff space $Y$ so that $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are ring isomorphic.